# Google Maps маркеры с одинаковыми координатами

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api

Не могу решить проблему с маркерами на карте. С сервера приходят объекты с одинаковыми координатами.
 [image]

Нужно сделать чтобы если у маркеров одинаковые координаты, то появлялся бы отдельный маркер с infoWindow с информацией обо всех маркерах в этих координатах.
Не знаю возможно есть и решение получше.
К сожалению не смог найти информацию по реализации такой вещи.

```
    var infoWin = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var markers = locations.map(function(location, i) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location.position, 
    icon: location.icon
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(evt) {
    infoWin.setContent(location.title);
    infoWin.open(map, marker);
  })
  return marker;
});    
}
var locations = [

  {
    position: {lat: 55.7511316, lng: 37.550269},
    map: map,
    title: '<a style="color: inherit;" target="_blank" href="/city/?element_id=598710">116.08 м², квартира новостройка, Краснопресненская наб, 14с1</a>',
    icon: {
      url: "/local/templates/nika/assets/img/marker.png",
      scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(36, 47)
    }
  }
  , 
  {
    position: {lat: 55.7511316, lng: 37.550269},
    map: map,
    title: '<a style="color: inherit;" target="_blank" href="/city/?element_id=598715">204.25 м², квартира новостройка, Краснопресненская наб, 14с1</a>',
    icon: {
      url: "/local/templates/nika/assets/img/marker.png",
      scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(36, 47)
    }
  }
  , 
  {
    position: {lat: 55.7511316, lng: 37.550269},
    map: map,
    title: '<a style="color: inherit;" target="_blank" href="/city/?element_id=598714">86.6 м², квартира новостройка, Краснопресненская наб, 14с1</a>',
    icon: {
      url: "/local/templates/nika/assets/img/marker.png",
      scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(36, 47)
    }
  }
];
```